# Oracle URL String

Tags: oracle, url, plsql

I have a table which contains a field of type VARCHAR2 and length of 255, which I use to store URLs. Running a SELECT query on it returns the data, as below:

```
SELECT URL FROM SERVICE WHERE ID = 1
```

returns the URL I have stored (in this case, file:///test.url/ is returned).

Running the same thing from a stored procedure, however, I get an empty box. All my other fields are filled in, and I get no errors about it. The URL field definitely contains the data, and I have made sure that the variable it is passed into is big enough to support it.

My question is this: in order to pass a URL-esque string out via a stored procedure, do I need to handle it in a particular way? A discussion with work colleagues about this presented the idea that the characters in the URL string may be causing some form of escape clause to be triggered, but I couldn't locate any further information on the subject.

**EDIT:** Part of the stored procedure used:

```
      SELECT        ...,
                    USER.SERVICE.URL,
                    ...

      FROM          USER.SITE

      -- More joins

      INNER JOIN    USER.SERVICE
      ON            USER.SITE.URLID = USER.SERVICE.ID          

      -- More joins

      WHERE         USER.SERVICE.ID = 1...
```

Comment: Post your stored procedure too!

The quick answer: no, you don't have to handle it in any special way.

Comment: can you include the code for your stored proc?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too big to post here, but I'll include the bit which tries to get it from the table.

Comment: I agree with @ppeterka, there is nothing special you'd need to do. If you want any more help, we'd need to see the full proc, or at least the signature (with parameter lists), any pertinent variable declarations, and the full select statement..

Answer (score 2):

like he said, you only execute the select but you're not storing it. you need to store the value of the field on a variable. In order to use it inside of a store procedure or package, you need to store it on a variable just like this

```
SELECT field INTO var FROM table
```

remember you don't need to handle it on a special way, because it's just a simple string. your procedure should look like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEMO(R_URL OUT VARCHAR2) IS  
BEGIN
 SELECT URL INTO R_URL FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running this from a stored procedure.  That means you need to select it into a variable.  From the sounds of it you're exposing the selected data to a client application, which means you need to pass it out somehow, e.g. by OUT parameters.

So one possible answer to your problem is that you are not populating the variable you think you're populating, or you're not passing the value to an OUT parameter (or whatever).

Anyway you bounce it, this is a debugging scenario.  If you can't post your code here (and I'm sure I speak for us all when I say I really don't want to pore over your large chunk o'code) then you'll need to go through it yourself.